# Getting exception during calling API by Eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, microservices, netflix-eureka

I've created the microservices with spring boot getting the exception during calling the URL http://localhost:8765/CURRENCY-EXCHANGE/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR from the local server

**exception details:**

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'DESKTOP-HG47DMC' after 2 queries 
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1013) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: Error has been observed at the following site(s):
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/CURRENCY-EXCHANGE/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler] Stack trace:
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1013) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:966) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:414) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(DnsResolveContext.java:625) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$400(DnsResolveContext.java:63) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:458) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) [netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) [netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) [netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) [netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) [netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605) [netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) [netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.trySuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:201) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
```

here is my **application.properties**

```
spring.application.name = api-gateway
server.port = 8765
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone =http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled= true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code snippet to your **application.properties** file of your microservices.

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet to your application.properties file of all your microservices(Naming server, API-Gatway and currency-exchange).

***eureka.instance.hostname=localhost***

if you get 404 response then please wait for 30 - 60 sec.